# print.eval option of source print data.table table

Tags: r, data.table

My question may be a simple one but I don't find a way to deal with it.

I have a script, Test.R with data.table tables in it and print that I use as a log.
I want to call this script from another R function.
For that, I use source with the option print.eval = T. My issue is that the data.table is printed as well as the result of the print, when I only want the print to be displayed.

Test.R:

```
library(data.table)

print("My log here")
t <- rnorm(10000, 1, 10)

t.dt <- data.table(t)
t.dt[, tt := pnorm(1, 0)]
```

run.R:

```
path <- my.path

source(paste0(path, "test.R"), print.eval  = TRUE)
```

I think source evaluate the data.table and print the result of eval. But I don't see then how to separate the print from the data.table.

thanks,

Comment: It works if you take `print.eval` out

Comment: problem solve, thanks.